# How can one "associate" test scripts with a Class in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I am looking for a way to somehow indicate in a file where a class/object has been declared that which test scripts test its functionality. The upside being that when changes are being made to the file in future, it is easy to identify which regression tests to run. Of course, before the changes are shipped into production the full suite will run anyways. However, given that the full suite can be huge, it would make life much easier if "Associated Regression Tests" can be quickly identified and run while making the changes.
The next logical feature will be to run all these associated tests with a single keyboard shortcut.
I am not looking for an automated way to identify the test scripts relevant to a Scala File. Instead, I just want to know if there is any standard place in the file where I can record this information. For example some special entry in scala docs etc

I am using Intellij Idea.

Edit: The test scripts are simple JUnit/ WordSpec ScalaTests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of "test scripts"? Whatever you're using for testing might have a way to do this, but we can't answer that if we don't know what you're using.

I'm not aware of any "standard" way of recording this particular information. I'd suggest writing a custom annotation; that way the information is at least slightly structured, which will make it easier to manipulate programmatically. You'll probably have to write your own IntelliJ plugin to get your keyboard shortcut.

Comment: The test scripts are simple JUnit/ WordSpec ScalaTests.